# Model Choices Field return null value on template

Tags: python, django

My model form has a coices field

```
class cekler(models.Model):
   bankalar = (
        ('Ziraat Bankası', 'Ziraat Bankası'),
        ('YapıKredi Bankası', 'YapıKredi Bankası'),
        ('Vakıflar Bankası', 'Vakıflar Bankası'),
        ('Teb', 'TEB'),
    )
    banka=models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=bankalar, verbose_name="Banka Adı:")
```

And my form;

```
class CekForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=cekler
        fields=[
               'banka',
                  ]
```

And my view like that;

```
def cekEkle (request):


    form = CekForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context ={
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request,'cek/form.html',context)
```

**How can I use this coices field on my template with HTML/Select-Option tag?**

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Can you share your template?

Comment: ```<select id="inputState" class="form-control">
            {% for value in form.banka %}
            <option value="{{ value }}" >{{ value }}</option>
            {% endfor %}

      </select>
```

_but this is return null. template error says that 'this field is required

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not passing the `name` attribute to the select field.

```
<select id="inputState" name="banka" class="form-control">
    {% for key, value in form.banka.field.choices %}
        <option value="{{ key }}" >{{ value }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

This should solve your problem.

Also, if you want, you can pass css classes to all your fields from backend also.

```
class CekForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CekForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["banka"].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    class Meta:
        model=cekler
        fields=[
               'banka',
                  ]
```

Then you can simply use `{{form.banka}}` in your template.

Comment: Thank You Aman. :)

But Now says that 

"Select a valid option. <option value = is not one of the available options."

I thing I make mistake from for loop. I loop 1 variable but I need 2 variable as 'key' and 'value'

but when I try "for value,key in form.banka" I get 

Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1.